# How to access a model's attribute from another model without a Foreign Key in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class PiggyBank(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField(default=None)
    depositor=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

class Withdrawal(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField(default=None)
    particulars=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    balance=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    voucher_number=models.IntegerField()
```

I want to access the `amount` field of `PiggyBank` from `Withdrawal` to write a method to calculate `balance`. But these models are not connected through a `Foreign Key`. How can I do that?

Comment: If these are not connected, then it makes no sense. Since you can not determine to which `PiggyBank` that `Withdraw` object is related, there are in essence two models that have nothing in common with each other.

Comment: A `ForeignKey` is not the problem, but you should by some means refer from `Withdrawal` model objects to the `PiggyBank`, otherwise there are simply no means to tell *what* `PiggyBank` should be used.

Comment: The `PiggyBank` is simply a database where a person deposits some amount on regular basis and the `Withdrawal` is used to record expenses made from that piggy bank. Only amount field from `PiggyBank` is supposed be used in `Withdrawal`. What are my options here then, in your opinion?

Comment: but the table for the `PiggyBank` can have *multiple* rows. How do you keep track what `PiggyBank` belongs to what `Withdtrawal`?

Comment: Once someone deposits some amount in `PiggyBank`, the amount automatically should be transferred into `Withdrawal`'s `balance`. And the further expenses will be made using the balance until it dries up and that someone deposits another round of money into the piggy bank. `balance` will keep on recalculating itself based on the amounts deposited and expenses made.